# Flutter - How to handle Non-Nullable Instance of widget properties

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I  am new to flutter and currently trying to simple animation on my component, but i keep getting a " Non-Nullable Instance " error, i checked out other video tutorials but theirs worked perfectly while mine keeps throwing errors.

Here's my code.

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> with TickerProviderStateMixin {

  Animation<Offset> sbarAnimation;
  AnimationController sbarAnimationController;

  @override

  void initState() {

    super.initState();

    sbarAnimationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
    );

    sbarAnimation = Tween<Offset>(
      begin: Offset(-1, 0),
      end: Offset(0, 0),
    ).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: sbarAnimationController,
        curve: Curves.easeInOut,
      ),
    );

  }
```

And then the code for the widget is below

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      body: Container(
        color: kBackgroundColor,
        child: Stack(

          children: [
            SafeArea(
              //so the background covers the entire app..
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  HomeScreenNavBar(),                     
                  ExploreCourseList(),
                ],
              ),
            ),

            SlideTransition(

              position: sbarAnimation,   // this is where i call the _animation

              child: SafeArea(
                child: SidebarScreen(),
                bottom: false,  
              ),
            ),
          ],

        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

below is the errors i keep getting, and most of the solutions i've seen did exactly the same thing, theirs works, but mine is giving this errors.. please what am i supposed to do.

[image]

Comment: When null-saftey is active on your project, you cannot define a non-nullable variable without assigning a value to it. This `Animation<Offset> sbarAnimation;` breaks. You can add a `?` to make the value nullable and fix the error. `Animation<Offset>? sbarAnimation;`

Comment: @daddygames i did that but it still didnt work, and also how do you flag nullsafety for sbarAnimationController without having errors.

Comment: My fault. I placed the `?` incorrectly in my comment. Looks like the community came through with actual answers. Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `late` keyword to initialize variables later as you are doing in your `initState`

```dart
late Animation<Offset> sbarAnimation;
late AnimationController sbarAnimationController;
```

Answer (score 1):

There two way to solve the issue.

1. Which already answered by **Juan Carlos Ramón Condezo**, using late keyword, where you must have to initialize it before using anywhere.
2. You can make the variable nullable. By using '?' After declaring the variable type.

```
Animation?<Offset> sbarAnimation;
AnimationController? sbarAnimationController;
```

So, you can check if the variable is null and initialize it when needed.